# I use jasmine to test the click event, and I will remove a class name, and I want to detect that the class name has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I want to check out. .menu -hiddenh is still there or not
Or check whether the code is normally executed after clicking

```
allFeeds.forEach(function(feed) {
    feed.id = feedId;
    feedList.append(feedItemTemplate(feed));
    feedId++;
});

feedList.on('click', 'a', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    $('body').addClass('menu-hidden');
    loadFeed(item.data('id'));
    console.log($('.menu-hidden').length);
    return false;
});

menuIcon.on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-hidden');
    console.log($('.menu-hidden').length);
});
```

Comment: It's bit unclear on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to check whether the element still has `menu -hidden` class, you use `hasClass('menu-hidden')`.

Comment: Write a test case to ensure that when the menu icon is clicked, the menu switches the visible state.this
* the test should contain two items: whether the menu is displayed when the party clicks the icon,
* is it hidden when you click again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe('The menu', function() {
 var $menuIcon, $body;
beforeEach(function() {
$menuIcon = $('.menu-icon-link');
$body = $('body');
});
afterEach(function() {
$menuIcon = null;
$body = null;
});
it('is hidden by default', function() {
expect($body.hasClass('menu-hidden')).toBeTruthy();
});
it('should change visibility when the menu icon is clicked', function() {
$menuIcon.trigger('click');
expect($body.hasClass('menu-hidden')).toBeFalsy();
$menuIcon.trigger('click');
expect($body.hasClass('menu-hidden')).toBeTruthy();
});
```